# tffs 2017 upgrade to 2018 web access denied

Tags: tfs

i would like to upgrade my production TFS 2017 to TFS 2018.
according to the requirement, it need SQL Server 2016 SP1, because some reason, i decide use a new production server for it.

Before doing the production upgrade, i do the upgrade test in my testing enviroment, the step is

1. Install SQL Server 2016 SP1
2. Restore the TFS 2017 Database
3. Install TFS 2018 Update 1
4. Start the TFS Upgrade Wizard using my existing db
5. Confirm the 8080 port is allow to connect

After finish, i can access the TFS web on the testing environment server by using http://localhost:8080/tfs or http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs (btw Chrome only can access using localhost)

When i connect http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs on client pc, it doesn't work, it show me

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

All my server have join domain and i try troubleshoot from tfs application to firewall, no any result on it.

Is there any step wrong or other problem on it?

---

**UPDATE:**

After i reinstall Windows OS, it's work.

Comment: Did you check the windows firewall?

Comment: yes, i've check the windows firewall. the 8080 port is exception from windows firewall

Comment: Have you tried the IP? just using IP instead of the SERVERNAME, then try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Using **IP** instead of the `SERVERNAME` in the URL, then try it
  again.
- Clean local caches from the client machine (TFS caches, Browser
  caches)
- Restart the TFS wensite from IIS manager.
- Restart IIS with command: `iisreset /noforce`
- Try changing the port number for you TFS
- [Rebuild the client cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/rebuild-client-cache?view=tfs-2018).

  > After you move, restore, rename, or fail over a data-tier or
  >   application-tier server, you must refresh the cache for tracking work
  >   items and users must refresh the version control cache on client
  >   computers.

---

**UPDATE1:**

Just try below things:

- Add the client machine name/IP to the hosts file. (The hosts file should be located under `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)
- Try to detach the collection then reattach it again
- Try to reconfigure the TFS.

---

**UPDATE2:**

Based on geraldlim's comment below :  Turn out that after reinstalling the OS and install IIS and TFS in a clear environment, it's working.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i tried the method you mentioned. I still cannot connect to the TFS website. Will it be the login permission problem from client ? When i connect the website on the server using IE, it'll show a window let me key in user id and password, but in client, it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: @geraldlim Have you tried other client machine? You need to firstly make sure the connectivity is OK between the client machine and the TFS server. If that works on the local server, in general it should be also working on client machine if the connectivity is OK. Just check the network, firewall, proxy etc ...

Comment: I've tried other client machine such as my colleague notebook and the same network segment server, but still cannot connect. I've tried close all the windows firewall, but still cannot connect to the TFS website, so i doubt maybe is the login permission problem

Comment: @geraldlim Base on the error message it should be an IIS related issue... Whatever just try other user accounts, do they have the same issue? If the same account can access from local server but not work on client machine, then it should not be the login permission problem.

Comment: @any-li-msft i tried reinstall IIS and ask colleague for helping test, still cannot connect on client machine, it show the same error message ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @geraldlim Just try adding the client machine name/IP to the hosts file. Try to detach the collection then reattach it again, it that still not work, then try to reconfigure the TFS. See the updated answer.

Comment: @any-li-msft i tried many times and doesn't work on it. I've tried one more thing is add a new website on IIS, and this website same as TFS Website, cannot be access. It should be IIS problem?

Comment: @geraldlim Based on the error message and your clarification, seems it's the IIS problem, dout that some IIS releated service is not running, just check for that.

Comment: @any-li-msft now i tried reinstall the OS, maybe can resolve the issue. I'll update here if any updated

Comment: @any-li-msft after i reinstall the OS and install IIS and TFS in a clear environment, it's work